# how to pass data retrieve from firebase in Table VIew Controller to View Controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, xcode9

### I am building a car sharing IOS App prototype.  My app is link to firebase, i can retrieve and display journey data in a table view but when trying to pass the data in another view controller the data do not display. Below are my table View controller and view controllers source codes.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var myIndex = 0
    var journeyList = [journeyModel]()

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return journeyList.count

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 150
    }


    // defining firebase reference var
    var refjourney: DatabaseReference!

    @IBOutlet weak var journeyTable: UITableView!

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! journeySearchTableViewCell

        var journe: journeyModel

        journe = journeyList[indexPath.row]
        print(journe.start!, journe.destination!, journe.date!, journe.driverName!)
        cell.driverNameLabel.text = journe.driverName
        cell.startLabel.text = journe.start
        cell.destinationLabel.text = journe.destination
        cell.dateLabel.text = journe.date

        return cell

    }
```

At this point the app functions correctly only faces issues when passing the data to another view controller

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Database.database().reference().child("Journey").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                self.journeyList.removeAll()

                for journey in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]  {

                    let journeyObject = journey.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let start = journeyObject?["startingPoint"]
                    let destination = journeyObject?["destinationPoint"]
                    let driverName = journeyObject?["driverName"]
                    let date = journeyObject?["tripDate"]
                    let id = journeyObject?["id"]

                    let journey = journeyModel(destination: destination as! String?, driverName: driverName as! String?, start: start as! String?, date: date as! String?, uid: id as! String?)

                    self.journeyList.append(journey)
                }
                self.journeyTable.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "logged", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var bsVC: bookSetViewController = segue.destination as! bookSetViewController

    }

    @IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

class bookSetViewController: UIViewController {

    var getStart = String()
    var getStop = String()
    var getDate = String()
    var getDriver = String()

    @IBOutlet weak var startingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var daterLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var driveLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        startingLabel.text! = getStart
        stopingLabel.text! = getStop
        daterLabel.text! = getDate
        driveLabel.text! = getDriver

    }
 }
```

---

```
import UIKit

class journeySearchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var startLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var destinationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var driverNameLabel: UILabel!
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

class journeyModel: NSObject {

    var driverName: String?
    var start: String?
    var destination: String?
    var date: String?
    var uid: String?


    init(destination: String?, driverName: String?, start: String?, date: String?, uid: String?) {

        self.driverName = driverName
        self.start = start
        self.destination = destination
        self.date = date
        self.uid = uid

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First things, first - don't share the whole project, just the bits that are needed.

The whole point of the prepare(for segue... is to get a handle to the new controller, and assign the values you need to pass over.

You will need to keep a track of which journey you're interested in.  There are many ways to do this, but the easiest might be to extend what you do on the click row

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    // assume you have defined journeySelected as a class-level instance of journeyModel
    journeySelected = journeyModel[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "logged", sender: self)
}
```

and then

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
var bsVC: bookSetViewController = segue.destination as! bookSetViewController

    bsVC.getStart = journeySelected.start
    // and for all the other fields
}
```

Comment: Hello Russel i try this method but Xcode displays 'Use of unresolved identifier journey'

Comment: OK - my mistake.  I though journey was a class-level instance!  I have made some edits to the solution above.  Basically, you need to keep a track of the particular journey you have selected, and then update those values in the destination VC as part of the prepare for segue.  Your current solution requires you to pass over each element of journey - but you could just have an instance of JourneyModel and make a single update